# Show some text in the login form only after the session expires (JSP pages)

Tags: jsp

i want to print some text in the login form when the session expires saying "Session Expired, plz login again". I thought sth which is working actually but i was wondering if there is another way that this can be done
the way i thought is this 
`//when the session expires`
`response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?param=0");`
 In the login.jsp i wrote:
`<% if ( request.getParameter("param") != null ) { %> Session Expired, plz login again<%}%>`
THis works fine. is there any other way to do this without passing parameters in the url? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way can be to use `Spring Security` framework
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html